# Datagridview doesnt auto select first row after filling datasource

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, datagridview

i have datagridview with 4 columns
[Nam] , [ID] , [Shuru] , [Payan]
second column ([ID]) is hidden and is used to gather some details about the data.
this is the Load code :

```
Private Sub SalMali_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DGV_SalMaliTableAdapter.Fill(Me.FDBDataSet.DGV_SalMali)
End Sub
```

which retrieves everything in DGV_SalMali table.
i know that datagridview automatically selects first row after a fill so i put a function in the Selection Change to retrieve data. here is the code :

```
    Private Sub DGV_SalMaliDataGridView_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.SelectionChanged
        refreshDT()
    End Sub
Public Sub refreshDT()
        Dim cnt As Integer = DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.Rows.Count
        If cnt = 0 Then
            GoTo line
        End If

        unlockAll()

        Dim sel As String = DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = SalMaliTA.GetData_SalMali_B_ID(sel)
        Dim dtr As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)

        TextBox1.Text = dtr.Item(4)
        MaskedTextBox1.Text = mc.MtoS(dtr.Item(1))
        MaskedTextBox2.Text = mc.MtoS(dtr.Item(2))
        CheckBox1.Checked = dtr.Item(3)

        Exit Sub
line:
        lockAll()
    End Sub
```

but when I call `refreshDT()` the selection doesn't work anymore. it throws an error on line 8 of refreshDT()

`sub { exactly here : Dim sel As String = DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value }`

> Thrown: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than
>   the size of the collection."
>   (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)  Exception Message = "Index was
>   out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection.", Exception Type = "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

datagridview has rows and i dont know what the problem is.
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're currently checking if there are any rows but not any selected rows:

```
Public Sub refreshDT()
    Dim cnt As Integer = DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.Rows.Count
    If cnt = 0 Then
        lockAll()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
        DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.Rows(0).Selected = true
    End If

    unlockAll()

    Dim sel As String = DGV_SalMaliDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = SalMaliTA.GetData_SalMali_B_ID(sel)
    Dim dtr As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)

    TextBox1.Text = dtr.Item(4)
    MaskedTextBox1.Text = mc.MtoS(dtr.Item(1))
    MaskedTextBox2.Text = mc.MtoS(dtr.Item(2))
    CheckBox1.Checked = dtr.Item(3)
End Sub
```